# Place the label in the top SWT

Tags: java, swt

I have two labels placed in the gridLayout. label 1 is just one word and the label 2 is 4 lines.
Since the label 2 is 4 lines, label 1 is verticaly centered, but I want that to be vertically in the top.

Below is the label settings I have used.

```
Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.WRAP);
GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING, GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING, false, false);
    gd.widthHint = 200;
label.setLayoutData(gd);
```

Kindly help me in placing the label alignment on top not in the center for label 1

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Javadoc of [`GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridData.html#HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING) and [`GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridData.html#VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING), you can see that it says:

> **Not recommended**. Use new GridData(**SWT.BEGINNING**, int, boolean, boolean) instead.

and

> **Not recommended**. Use new GridData(int, **SWT.BEGINNING**, boolean, boolean) instead.

Always use the `SWT` alignment constants:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    Label left = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    left.setText("LEFT");
    Label right = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    right.setText("RIGHT\nRIGHT\nRIGHT\nRIGHT");

    GridData data = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.BEGINNING, false, false);
    left.setLayoutData(data);
    data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    right.setLayoutData(data);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]